# Probability of an event from the joint probabilities

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

If the event A is the event, {I am leaving work early today}, and B is the event, {there is a football game that I want to watch}. Given the following joint probabilities:

p(I am leaving work early, there is a football game that I want to watch this afternoon) = .1

p(I am leaving work early, there is not a football game that I want to watch this afternoon) = .05.

p(I am not leaving work early, there is not a football game that I want to watch this afternoon) = .65

How do I go about finding the probability B, that there is a football game that I want to watch this afternoon?

Comment: Note that p(no football game) = p(I am leaving work early, no football game) + p(I am not leaving work early, no football game). After that, you can find your probability as $1 - p(no football game)$.

Comment: Tip: Use a contingency table for probabilities. Have you tried that?

Answer (score 1):

\begin{align*}
P(B)&=1-P(B^c)\\
&=1-P((A\cap B^c) \cup (A^c\cap B^c))\\
&=1-P(A\cap B^c)-P(A^c\cap B^c)\\
&=1-0.05-0.65\\
&=0.3
\end{align*}